# Bash script to scan for iBeacons and use GPIO on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, ibeacon

I followed a tutorial to illuminate an LED on a Raspberry Pi so that when an iBeacon detected an LED is turned on using the GPIO pins but I need to alter the script so that the LED goes off again when the iBeacon is no longer detected.

The script at the moment is:

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 1 out
trap "gpio write 1 0" exit
while read line
do
    if [[ `echo $line | grep "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 1" ` ]]; then
        gpio write 1 1
    fi     
done
```

Which is being called by:

```
$ beacon scan -b | ./scriptName
```

The out put of `beacon scan` is:

```
pi@pibeacon ~ $ sudo beacon scan
BLE Beacon Scan ...
iBeacon     UUID: 92AB49BE-4127-42F4-B532-90FAF1E26491   MAJOR: 1       MINOR: 1       POWER:    -59   RSSI: -62 
iBeacon     UUID: 92AB49BE-4127-42F4-B532-90FAF1E26491   MAJOR: 1       MINOR: 1       POWER: -59   RSSI: -65 
iBeacon     UUID: 92AB49BE-4127-42F4-B532-90FAF1E26491   MAJOR: 1       MINOR: 1       POWER: -59   RSSI: -65
```

Continuously updating all the time the iBeacon is detected and just stops when the iBeacon is undetected.

The aim is to have a script run all the time and use the output of the `beacon scan` command to determine if the LED should be on or off - if the iBeacon is detected the LED should be on and if the iBeacon is then moved out of range the LED turn off again. The existing strip turns the LED on once and then the only way to reset the situation is to stop the script and start it again.
Thanks

Comment: What is the content of `line` exactly? you very likely don't even need `grep` at all. Try: `if [[ $line = *"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 1"* ]]; then`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf the line variable is filled fron stdin, then it is the `beacon scan -b` output.

Comment: The beacon scan command is outputting a huge list  of the uuids of iBeacons it sees and then grep is used to find data in this output. Is it possible to tell that the 'beacon scan' output hasn't been updated recently or would it be better to create a script that started the beacon scan command every few seconds so the output is cleared and then the same if statement can be used?

Comment: Sorry yes I have, but the LED stays on when the beacon is off.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the output of `beacon scan -b`? (edit your question, because from your question, it's not clear what you're asking).

Comment: So you want to execute `gpio write 1 1` each time `beacon` issues a line `iBeacon     UUID: 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 1   MAJOR: 1       MINOR: 1       POWER:    whatever   RSSI: whatever`? if it's the case, please make it clear in your question.

Comment: Edited again! Sorry @gniourf_gniourf, and thank you for your patience!

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking for. Don't expect us to all know everything about raspberry pi and beacon. This is a programming site. Maybe you'll have more chances if you ask on the dedicated website http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ or if you can state your question in a way that's understandable without prior knowledge of raspberry pis and beacon.

Comment: You don't have any code in your script that would turn off the LED when the iBeacon isn't detected. Your `while` statement is effectively an infinite loop because the `beacon scan` command never finishes. The code in the `trap` statement is never executed because the script never exits.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could accomplish it with your existing code is to set a variable to a timestamp inside your if statement.  Then, outside your if statement (but inside the while), you can compare the current time to the timestamp.  If enough time has passed since the beacon was detected (say 5 seconds), you code can turn off the LED.

The disadvantage of this approach is that if no beacons are detected at all, your code will block on the `read line` statement.  So this is only workable if you know for sure at least one beacon will always be around to keep your program running.  This sort of programming is not ideally suited to a simple bash script, because you really need two threads to handle this.  But if you want to keep your same basic toolset, this is a decent option.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a (bad?) solution and thought I'd share it here. It has the effect of when the beacon is detected the light flashes and then when the beacon goes out of range the light stops flashing. I set this code to run on startup of the Pi and has fulfilled the function I needed (a very rough proof of concept prototype!).

I used the very good Radius Networks Development Kit (which is where the original script is from) and would highly recommend that if anyone else is interested in messing about with iBeacons.

```
#!/bin/bash
gpio mode 1 out
trap "gpio write 1 0" exit
while read line
do
    if [[ $line = *"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 1"* ]]; then
       gpio write 1 1
    fi     
gpio write 1 0
done
```